# Sonar lint : "compareTo" results should not be checked for specific values

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am compare two values and getting sonar lint throwing `"Only the sign of the result should be examined" this issue`.

Code :

```
if (recBalanceAmt.compareTo(recRolloverEligibility) == 1) {
     recExpAmt = recBalanceAmt.subtract(recRolloverEligibility);
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sonar is suggesting to check the result of `compareTo` against `0`, not if it returns directly `1`, `-1`.

```
if (recBalanceAmt.compareTo(recRolloverEligibility) > 0) {
```

You can find the reason for this suggestion in the [compareTo() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

> Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this
>   object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: Why? compare with 1 is not OK? or is there any issue with comparing with 1?

Comment: by contract, a compareTo method can return any positive  value, not necessarily 1, so if the method returns 2 and you compare the result to 1 your condition won't be satisified.

Comment: I can see everytime it is returning +1 for greater and -1 for smaller. Can there be any scenraio I can create where it will return -2 instead of -1?